# SFSpeechRecognitionTaskDelegate delegate methods are not getting called

Tags: delegates, speech-recognition, ios10, speech-to-text

I am working on speech to text iOS 10 feature.

I want SFSpeechRecognitionTaskDelegate's delegate methods to be called for checking the completed results.

```
func speechRecognitionTask(_ task: SFSpeechRecognitionTask, didFinishRecognition recognitionResult: SFSpeechRecognitionResult);
```

But its any delegate method is not getting called.
Also I am curious about why its .delegate property which is not available for setting delegate to self.

Any Help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Edited: 
Also, The delegate Property set by the protocol is not found in the documentaion. i.e.

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<SFSpeechRecognitionTaskDelegate> delegate;
```

is not available in SFSpeechRecognitionTask.h file.
Is it necessary that we need property for that?

Comment: can you show some code?

Comment: Ah! Forgot to comment here again. There is explicit method for this delegate to call. recognitionTaskWithRequest:delegate: method is available for this. 
I found this method in SFSpeechRecognizer documentaion. 
Here you will get it: https://developer.apple.com/reference/speech/sfspeechrecognizer?language=objc

Answer (score 2):

use:

```
 self.speechRecognizer.recognitionTask(with:  self.recognitionRequest!, delegate: self)
```

Comment: If I need to use the result handler method

recognitionTask = speechRecognizer?.recognitionTask(with: request, resultHandler: {result, error in
//code
}

its difficult to use both delegate and handler methods.

Answer (score 0):

refer this article, It contains demo app on speechkit in swift,

https://www.appcoda.com/siri-speech-framework/

It works fine for me.

Comment: So are you using SFSpeechRecognitionTaskDelegate's delegate methods?
Can you share me the code snippet of SFSpeechRecognitionTaskDelegate methods?

Comment: I am using SFSpeechRecognizerDelegate.

Comment: Ok. I want a procedure where, after certain pause in speech, the recognizer should stop working and it should give the final result of the speech recognition. I am sending this text as input to my SearchView Controller. So I need the complete sentence spoken by user

Comment: Have you refer apple's document for this?

Comment: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/64832

someone else is also facing the same issue. Have you tried calling the SFSpeechRecognitionTaskDelegate methods?

Comment: @KAR delegate method is not calling perfectlly, there is only two methods are calling.